# How to use database view in test cases

Tags: python, django

I am unable to use database view in test cases. other hand i am able to use those database view in front end function . but when i try to get data from view in it return null in test case.

Please give me suggestion for use database views in test cases

Comment: Have you made a proper fixture?

Comment: @limelights Please give me any example for how we made a proper fixture.

Answer (score 4):

By database view do you mean you are using an unmanaged model which represents an underlying database view (as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed))?

If so, I have found that, during unit testing, Django ignores the `managed = False` setting in the model meta and creates an actual table.  Unless you explicitly populate this in your `setUp` this will be empty.

A quick-and-dirty way of getting around this is to explicitly drop the table and create the view in your test case's `setUp` method, like this:

```
# Imports
from django.db import connection
from django.core.files import File

...

        # Inside your test case setUp method
        # Drop the table
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        # See note 1
        cursor.execute("SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myproject_myview; SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;")
        cursor.close()

        # Create the view
        # See note 2
        file_handle=open('/full/path/to/myproject/sql/create_myview.sql','r+')
        sql_file=File(file_handle)
        sql = sql_file.read()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql) 
        cursor.close()
```

Notes:

1. This is to get around a MySQL problem so might not apply to your case.  The table will only exist the first time `setUp` is run.  If you try to drop the table on a subsequent pass MySQL will generate warnings - this code suppresses them.
2. This file contains creation code for a single view in the format `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myproject_myview AS...`.   I've found that trying to execute a file containing multiple commands with the same cursor also causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by a database view you mean accessing a database inside a view.

That being said, I think your problem is that you dont have a test database that Django is trying to test against.

This is how you start off with that and its called fixtures. (You could do this with SQL as well but **I** think it's easier with fixtures).

The easiest being using the `dumpdata` command provided by Django.

`python manage.py dumpdata`

This will create a file, which will be in your apps directory, which you can use in your tests like this:

For example

`myDjangoProject/myCoreApp/fixtures/myCoreApp_views_testdata.json`

NOTE: The `myCoreApp` won't be named this.

You could also set a `FIXTURES_DIR` setting in your `settings.py` as to tell Django where to look for fixtures in the future.

To use a fixture then in your tests you do the following

```
class SomeViewThatIWantToTest(TestCase): #Note, you must use django.test.TestCase
    fixtures = ['core_views_testdata.json']
```

After this you should be able to access your data in your views as normal.
This might require some tuning to fit your exact example so I added a link to the official docs at the bottom!

Good luck and please do correct me if I'm wrong! :)

[Read more about this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures)