# How to extend Django's test database with custom SQL view?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm using Django 2.1 with MySQL.
I have one custom SQL view, which is bound with a model with `Meta` `managed = False`. Django's TestCase has no idea how the view is created, so I'd like to provide SQL command to create this view. The best option would be to do this on database create, but I have no idea how to do that.

What I've done so far was to override `TestCase`'s `setUp` method. It looks like that:

```
class TaskDoneViewTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Create custom SQL view
        """
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        file_handle = open('app/tests/create_sql_view.sql', 'r+')
        sql_file = File(file_handle)
        sql = sql_file.read()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        cursor.close()

    def test_repeatable_task_done(self):
        # ...

    def test_one_time_task_done(self):
        # ...
```

I've got this solution from similar SO post: [How to use database view in test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687418/how-to-use-database-view-in-test-cases). It would be a nice temporary solution, but the problem is with all those 2 test cases active I'm getting following error:

```
$ python manage.py test app.tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...E..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_repeatable_task_done (app.tests.test_views.TaskDoneViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asmox/AppDev/Python/bubblechecklist/project_root/app/tests/test_views.py", line 80, in setUp
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/asmox/AppDev/Python/bubblechecklist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/asmox/AppDev/Python/bubblechecklist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/asmox/AppDev/Python/bubblechecklist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/home/asmox/AppDev/Python/bubblechecklist/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 437, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

For some reason this error doesn't happen when I have only one test case active (why?).This error remains until I change my test's base class from `TestCase` to `TransactionTestCase`.

Well, I would ask why this happen and if there is any solution to get it okay with simple `TestCase` class, because my test for now has nothing to do with transactions and I find this working solutions a bit too dirty, but...

I would more likely stick to the main issue, that is, to globally (for all my test cases) do the following thing:

*When testing database is created, do one more custom SQL from provided file. It is going to create required view*

Can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: `TestCase` wraps each test in two transactions, one at the class level and one at the test level. `setUp` runs for each test, but you can use [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) to set up your db at the class level. However I'm still not sure this would work (try it). Otherwise, do this in your [`setUpClass()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase) method.

Comment: Thank you, `setUpTestData` did the thing. Do you suggest to create inherited class like `TestCaseWithViews(TestCase)` with this function for all my further tests, or is there another method like adding something to `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, just create your parent class from which all your test cases will inherit. settings.py has nothing to do with it (and should certainly not be changed for the purpose of testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for `TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#testcase), you'll see that it wraps each test in a double transaction, one at the class level and one at the test level. The `setUp()` method runs for each test and is thus inside this double wrapping.

As shown in the above mentioned docs, it is suggested you use `setUpTestData()` to set up your db at the class level. This is also where you'd add initial data to your db for all your tests to use.